# How to align list data side by side in page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to align data list like this.

[image]

But I get output like this

[image]

I tried following code

```
$rawResult = unserialize($rawResult->sections);
$ans = array(0,1,2,3,4,5);
foreach ($rawResult as $questionKey => $questionArray) {
  foreach ($questionArray['answers'] as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value['given'][0], $ans)){
    $answers[$key] = $value['given'][0];
  }
  }
  foreach ($questionArray['questions'] as $id => $val) {
    if (!preg_match("/How stressful has it been/i", $val['name'])) {
    /*if($val['type'] == 'Single'){*/
      $questions[$val['id']] = $val['name'];
    }
  }
}
ob_start();
global $csa_answers;
asort($answers);
$i=0;
$m=0;
$l=0;
$y=0;
global $pdf;

?>
<table class="progress-bar-container assessment-result" style="text-align:center;">
      <tr>
        <td><h3 style="font-weight: 700;font-size: 25px;line-height: 32px;color: #000;margin-bottom: 6px;font-family: 'Karla';">CSA Questions/Ratings</h3></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><span style="text-align: center;">Every CSA question and your response is listed below. Each question started out with the phrase,<br>
"How much have you been stressed by.....?"</span></td>
      </tr>
      </table>

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="text-align:left;" width="620">

          <tr>
            <td><table width="310"><tr>
            <td width="225" style="background-color: #EAE9E8;font-size:12px;">QUESTION</td>
            <td width="80" style="background-color: #EAE9E8;font-size:12px;">RATING</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
          <?php foreach ($answers as $id => $ans) {
            if(isset($questions[$id])){
              $i++; ?>
              <td style="<?php echo $c;?>"><span style="font-size:10px;"><?php echo str_replace('How much have you been stressed by ','',stripslashes($questions[$id]));?></span></td>
              <td style="<?php echo $c;?>"><span style="font-size:10px;"><i><?php echo $csa_answers[$ans];?></i></span></td>
              <?php
                if ($l==0) {
                  $c= "background-color: #EAE9E8;";
                  $l++;
                }
                else{
                  $c="";
                  $l=0;

                }
                $i = 0;
                $m++;
              echo "</tr><tr >";

              $y++;
              if ($y==34) {
                $l==0;
                echo '<td></td><td></td></tr></table></td><td ><table width="310"><tr>
            <td width="225" style="background-color: #EAE9E8;font-size:12px;">Question</td>
            <td width="80" style="background-color: #EAE9E8;font-size:12px;">Rating</td>
            </tr><tr>';
              }

            }
          }
          ?>
      <td></td><td></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr>
<?php echo '<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><span class="score-desc" style="font-size:9px;">The choices for answering each question were:</span><br>
        <span class="csmith-right-margin" style="font-size:9px;"> Not at all (Stress Free) </span>
        <span class="csmith-right-margin" style="font-size:9px;"> A little bit </span>
        <span class="csmith-right-margin" style="font-size:9px;"> Moderately </span>
        <span class="csmith-right-margin" style="font-size:9px;"> Quite a bit </span>
        <span class="csmith-right-margin" style="font-size:9px;"> Extremely </span>
        <span class="csmith-right-margin" style="font-size:9px;"> Does not apply  </span></td></tr>';
           ?>
    </table>
    <?php
  $content = ob_get_clean();
  return $content;
```

I tried many times to change the code but still get the wrong output. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The two column view? If so, please edit your question and make it clear what part of the example you are trying to replicate

Answer (score 0):

Table is not good for this, you can use:

```
  1. <div style='display:inline-block'>Column 1</div> <div style='display:inline-block'>Column 2</div>
 2. Use css flex box (prefer for responsive page reason).
 3. Or if you familiar with table use <div style='display:table'></div> as css table not HTML table
```